# geom_sf and geom_point, how to assign colors based on the points inserted on the map to the corresponding types in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I need to insert multiple points on the map using ggplot. I would like to display in the legend the amount of colors and shapes corresponding to the types registered in points$types.
I also need the value of point$obj to be printed on the map along with the insertion of the coordinate.
However, I managed to get to that code, but I can't assign the colors and shapes. How to solve this problem?
Here is an example of what a plot should look like: the colored coordinates and the print labes:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
library(geobr)
library(ggspatial)
library(ggplot2)


BR <- read_state(year=2018)

points
obj x           y           types
1   F1  -43.18669   -22.901724  A
2   F2  -43.31534   -22.779600  A
3   F3  -67.82527   -9.984939   B
4   F4  -72.74519   -7.610681   B
5   F5  -35.93844   -9.308399   B
6   F6  -63.13576   -4.105584   B
7   F7  -60.00568   -2.049304   B
8   F8  -35.91194   -7.217137   C
9   F9  -35.04254   -7.998586   C
10  F10 -48.26501   -18.889202  C
11  F11 -45.23610   -21.238526  D
12  F12 -43.71210   -22.244824  E


# plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data=BR,
    color="black",
    size=.1, show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(data=points,
             aes(x=x, y= y, fill = as.factor(types)),
             size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999","#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#3399FF"))+
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude", fill = "Types", size=8 ) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(geobr)
library(ggspatial)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(sf)

BR <- read_state(year=2018)

# plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=BR,
    color="black",
    size=.1, show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(data=points,
             aes(x=x, y= y, color = types, size = types)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999","#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#3399FF")) +
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude", color = "Types", size="Types") +
geom_label_repel(data=points, aes(x=x, y= y, label=obj)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

To add the names of the capitals, first, we need to compute the centroid of each state polygon as the coordinates where to draw their names.

```
BR <- cbind(BR, st_coordinates(st_centroid(BR)))
```

It will give a warning which basically says that centroid coordinates using longitude/latitude data (i.e. WGS84) are not exact, which is perfectly fine for drawing purposes. Then use the following code

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=BR,
    color="black",
    size=.1, show.legend = T) +
  geom_text(data = BR, aes(X, Y, label = abbrev_state), colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data=points,
             aes(x=x, y= y, color = types, size = types)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999","#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#3399FF")) +
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude", color = "Types", size="Types") +
  geom_label_repel(data=points, aes(x=x, y= y, label=obj)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]
**Data**

```
points <- structure(list(sl = 1:12, obj = c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", 
"F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10", "F11", "F12"), x = c(-43.18669, 
-43.31534, -67.82527, -72.74519, -35.93844, -63.13576, -60.00568, 
-35.91194, -35.04254, -48.26501, -45.2361, -43.7121), y = c(-22.901724, 
-22.7796, -9.984939, -7.610681, -9.308399, -4.105584, -2.049304, 
-7.217137, -7.998586, -18.889202, -21.238526, -22.244824), types = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Yes, the labels too need to be added to the coordinates on map.

Comment: That was it.  I know it's not part of the initial question, but how do I get the names of the capitals to appear BR$abbrev_state. Best reagards.

Comment: Thank you very much!